# Constructor passed as arg in Firebase setValue() not calling construtor

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have connected my Android app to Firebase real time database.

I have a simple model class which I am using to send to Firebase.

Constructor code:

```
public People(String name, int age, boolean single) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.single = single;
}
```

The code on the `onCreate()` method in `MainActivity.java` is:

```
myRef.setValue(new People("John Smith", 21, false));
myRef.setValue(new People("Sarah Smith", 30, true));
myRef.setValue(new People("Joe Bloggs", 50, false));
```

The first `setValue()` works fine. The Firebase is updated with name="John Smith", age=21, single=false.

Problem #1

But the second value should replace John Smith's entry completely but the age comes up with 25 (I set Sarah's age at 25 previously but it somehow remembers that instead of assigning it with 30). When I go into debug mode, Android Studio actually passes on 25 as the arg.

Problem #2

Third `setValue()` isn't even triggered in the sense that the

```
new People("Joe Bloggs", 50, false)
```

constructor isn't called. The app stops running after the second `setValue()` call.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why app stops? Can you post stack trace? and full People class.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the reference of Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#setValue(java.lang.Object)):

> In addition, you can set instances of your own class into this location, provided they satisfy the following constraints:
>
> 1. **The class must have a default constructor that takes no arguments**
> 2. The class must define public getters for the properties to be
>      assigned. Properties without a public getter will be set to their
>      default value when an instance is deserialized

You can add the following code and try again:

```
public People() {
    // empty
}
```

Comment: yeah sorry I didnt write that in my question. There was a default constructor.